Social login with google/facebook via Laravel API
I am trying to implement social login with laravel API. 
I have implemented the Social login for web. And it's working perfectly.  
Facing problem to implement the same feature for React Native application via API.
I have created a public API Route for the social login via API. 
Ex: https://example.com/api/social-login/{provider}/callback
Method : POST
Req Body : access_token (This token getting from login via Gmail account at React Native App)
After getting this access token i am passing as Req Body to the API.
Here is Code snippet :
public function handleProviderCallback(Request $request, $provider){
   try{
       $accessToken    = $request->access_token
       $socialProvider = $socialProvider = Socialite::driver($provider)->stateless()->userFromToken($accessToken);
       // Rest of code here

   }
   catch(\Throwable $e){
      dd(
         $e->getMessage(),$e->getFile(),$e->getLine()
      );
   }

}

And Getting below error:  

{"message":"Client error: GET https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo?prettyPrint=false resulted in a 401 Unauthorized response:{"error":"invalid_request","error_description": "Invalid Credentials"}

Can anyone assist?

Facebook & Google both updated their Social Login process.
 public function handleProviderCallback(Request $request, $provider){
    $loginService = new LoginService(); // Don't forget to import the LoginService.php at top
     if($loginService->isLoginWithGoogle($provider)) {
           $response = Http::get("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token={$accessToken}");

      if (!$response->successful()) {
             throw new \Exception($response->body(), requestResponse()::UNAUTHORIZED_ACTION);
                }

          $socialProvider = json_decode($response->body(), true);
               // Your Logic Here
      }

      // Facebook
      if($loginService->isLoginWithFacebook($provider)) {
          $response = Http::get("https://graph.facebook.com/v21.0/me?fields=id,name,email&access_token={$accessToken}");

          // When it's failed to successful
          if (!$response->successful()) {
               throw new \Exception($response->body(), requestResponse()::UNAUTHORIZED_ACTION);
           }

           $socialProvider = json_decode($response->body(), true);
           // Your Logic Here
     }
 } // handleProviderCallback method closing

  // LoginService.php
  public function isLoginWithGoogle($data){
     return $data == "google"; // returning true/false
  }

  public function isLoginWithFacebook($data){
     return $data == "facebook"; // returning true/false
  }

Important Note: $provider is a dynamic  parameter which is receiving "facebook","google", "twitter","LinkedIn"
etc from the URL.
Note: Always keep your eyes on official documentation.
 Thanks

Please explain how this solves the issue. Code-only answers are not good answers. What even is $loginService? This is not defined in OP's code - "Always keep your eyes on official documentation" - Which documentation? Wouldn't it be helpful to actually add a reference to the documentation used when writing this answer?

@DarkBee Updated the answer. please let me know if you need more details.
